# Waiting for fragments in viewpager to inflate

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that used a single layout to show all output etc.  I have converted it to a multi-tabbed app by using

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "Tab 1");
adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTwo(), "Tab 2");
adapter.addFragment(new FragmentThree(), "Tab 3");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem is I can no longer access the fragments during onCreate (just after the above code) because I now get errors that they are null object references.

For example if I try and set the caption of a button with this code just after the above

```
Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
button.setText("BLAH");
```

I get the null object error.

I was using the onCreate to setup text, a google map view and check for GPS, so it is more than just a simple button change.

How can I be sure the all the page layouts have finished inflating and it is safe for me to access the objects within them?  I want to get all the tab/page contents updated when the app is first launched.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to move this code into the fragments themselves. You can hook into `onCreateView()`, `onViewCreated()`, `onActivityCreated()`, or any of the many other Fragment lifecycle methods.

If you need to execute this code inside the activity for some reason, then you would create a new method in your activity and trigger it from one of these Fragment lifecycle methods. Maybe something like this:

```
// in the activity
public void onFragmentStartup() {
    Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    button.setText("BLAH");
}

// in the fragment
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onFragmentStartup();
}
```